# Unable to use activator on my Mac - get a timeout exception when I try and make an app from template

Tags: macos, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

So I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing

It all seems installed - i.e. all the commands work but when I try and call:

```
activator new my-first-app play-scala
```

I get the following:

```
Fetching the latest list of templates...


Could not fetch the updated list of templates.  Using the local cache.
Check your proxy settings or increase the timeout.  For more details see:
http://typesafe.com/activator/docs

OK, application "another-app" is being created using the "play-scala" template.

akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://default/user/template-cache#1575831997]] after [10000 ms]
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:333)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:117)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:597)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Scheduler.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.executeBucket$1(Scheduler.scala:419)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:423)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:375)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And nothing happens.

I just installed it on a PC in my house under the same network so I don't think my connection is the issue. I'm not using a proxy either..

Got any ideas? I've been trying to get this working for over a day now.

I'm on OSX Yosemite by the way.

Comment: Have you checked the link on Typesafe's website? It may be a known issue. Have you tried increasing the timeout as suggested?

Comment: @vptheron Yeah I increased the timeout and it made the project but trying to run it gives me server time out errors :/

Comment: What's the version of Typesafe Activator? It appears as if a network card issue.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Activator 1.2.12

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have timeouts too, especially while working in the university on some sloppy WLAN.
There are two types of activator, the usual light-weight one and the offline version. In the second, all repositories are present so the activator does not need to gather anything from the internet.

When you go to https://www.playframework.com/download ... look for the offline distribution (around 400MB) and install it like the normal activator.
If this solves your problem, there was something wrong with the activator trying to get something from a repository (you said that you can run the project but get server timeouts).

[EDIT]: You can also set the timeout to 30 seconds and see if this helps

```
activator -Dactivator.timeout=30s new "project name"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I get in from work.